# Xcode flagging simple C++20 snippet as error but compiling correctly using latest LLVM 10.0.0 Clang compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang, c++20

I have recently been reading up on some of the C++20 features and been particularly interested in playing with *concepts*. I decided to get the source code of the latest LLVM 10.0.0 off of git so that I could compile it following the guide [here](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) and get the latest clang, the associated OpenMP implementation, and some other things. To help with developing in Xcode, I also built the project using the `-DLLVM_CREATE_XCODE_TOOLCHAIN=ON` so it would produce a Toolchain output I could use in Xcode.

The build process went fine and it generated the desired products like `clang++`, `libomp`, the Xcode Toolchain, etc. I switched to the LLVM generated toolchain in Xcode, after restarting Xcode, updated the build settings like the C++ dialect being `c++20`, and I have noticed a couple things. First, the following basic sample code compiles and runs successfully:

```
template <typename T>
concept always_satisfied = true;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the annoying thing with Xcode is that the IDE is flagging the `concept always_satisfied = true` line as an error, as shown in the below image, implying that Xcode cannot recognize the C++20 keyword `concept` or something along those lines.

[image: Xcode not recognizing concept keyword]

How can I fix this problem? I have tried clearing my `DerivedData/` for the project to see if that might help, since I have read some problems like this being resolved in the past with this fix, yet it still has not resolved the situation.

Comment: `Xcode` uses clang, so your problem is just configuration issue. How did you test for "clang" and how did you configured `Xcode` project (is it a pure `Xcode` project or you are using `cmake` or something similar).

Comment: So your code compiles but the pre-compiler doesn't recognize concepts? It sounds similar to the issue I had with Visual Studio and VS Code where I would compile C++20 features fine, but Intellisense would keep flagging my lines. What happens if you #include <concepts>? I don't have a Mac to test right now, but Travis for OSX fails to build as it doesn't find the concepts header at all (see bottom of https://travis-ci.org/github/hsandt/cpp-platform-adventure/jobs/746503838 for an example)